# SQL while loop matches no entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to create a while loop in sql which creates 100 empty entries into my database.

My table structure looks like:
[image]

My sql query looks like:

```
SET @id := 1;

WHILE @id <= 100 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Sticker (id, sticker_url, user_name, user_nickname, latitude, longitude, adress) VALUES(@id, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 1.2, 1.1, 'NULL');
    SET @id = @id + 1;
END
```

After execute the query the result is: "no errors"
But the query create no entries, it's a bit strange.

SELECT @@version: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

thanks..

Comment: just to make sure it's getting into your `WHILE` loop, toss a `PRINT 'HI'`  or `SELECT 'hello'` in there.  Could be a problem outside of this loop :) and it's never getting in.

Comment: Do you get 0 affected rows ? or you get 100 affected rows but you don't see them after that?

Comment: 0 affected row.. nothing happens. No error, no new entries.

Comment: @sniperd the print statement only works outside the while loop

Comment: sounds like it's not even getting into the `WHILE` loop, weird.  should the `SET` be like this?  `SET @id = 1;`  and I think you need a `DO` after the condition of the `WHILE`

Comment: Is this done in a [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)?

Comment: `WHILE`... `WHILE END` blocks only in stored programs not in "plain" SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a `mysql` box handy right now but I *think* this is what you want:

```
SET @id := 1;

WHILE @id <= 100 DO
    INSERT INTO Sticker (id, sticker_url, user_name, user_nickname, latitude, longitude, adress) VALUES(@id, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 1.2, 1.1, 'NULL');
    SET @id := @id + 1;
END WHILE;
```

I'm sorry I can't test that.  But I think the main thing missing is that you want a `DO` instead of a `BEGIN`.  I bet the `BEGIN` was starting a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is with the colon in

```
SET @id := 1;
```

since the proper SET syntax is

> SET var_name = value

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-statement.html

and missing DO in WHILE DO

Comment: The feature is implemented since v8 of mysql, my server runs with 5.7..